# for loops with callback functions in jQuery or how to avoid them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small animation in jQuery that needs to quickly show words and non-words for a determined amount of time in milliseconds upon a click.

```
var arr = ['GOAT', 'BEAVER', 'TIGER', 'ELEPHANT', 'FOX', 'BEAR', 'BEE', 'CAT', 'DOG', 'MOUSE', 'LION', 'FISH', 'SHRIMP', 'HEN', 'GOOSE', 'COW', 'CROCODILE', 'DEER', 'MOOSE', 'HIPPOPOTAMUS', 'WOLF', 'RACCOON', 'HARE', 'OTTER', 'DOLPHIN', 'WHALE', 'CHICK'];

var narr = ['REQXARDE', 'YORSTDAJ', 'AWQPQQQR', 'FJSJAJAA', 'QQWPEEET', 'ALALOIYE', 'BOUILAARW', 'NVOSAQEWW', 'WARTYDIOS', 'SUPARWLISS', 'WQQQAPXXX', 'OOOSAAOEA', 'SSIUDHFWW', 'AWWWEIPP', 'AAZXDOUP', 'SURPAAARJ', 'AALDJWWA', 'WEEJSYSJ', 'REQXARDE', 'YORSTDAJ', 'AWQPQQQR', 'FJSJAJAA', 'QQWPEEET', 'ALALOIYE', 'BOUILAARW'];

var key = ['jQuery', 'Javascript', 'css3', 'stackoverflow', 'html5', 'animation'];

/* This selects a random value from each array */
function narr_val() { return narr[Math.floor(Math.random() * narr.length)]; }
function arr_val() { return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]; }
function key_val() { return key[Math.floor(Math.random() * key.length)]; }

$( "#foo" ).bind("click tap", function(){

$("#foo").unbind( "click" ); 

//Block 0
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(500).html('Attention!').fadeOut(1,function(){
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(500).html('In 3...').fadeOut(1,function(){
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(500).html('2...').fadeOut(1,function(){
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(500).html('1...').fadeOut(1,function(){
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(500).html('Go!').fadeOut(1,function(){

//Block 1
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(175).html(narr_val()).fadeOut(1,function(){
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(40).html(key_val()).fadeOut(1,function(){
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(175).html(narr_val()).fadeOut(1,function(){
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(320).html(arr_val()).fadeOut(1,function(){
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(40).html(narr_val()).fadeOut(1,function(){

//Block 2
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(175).html(narr_val()).fadeOut(1,function(){
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(40).html(key_val()).fadeOut(1,function(){
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(175).html(narr_val()).fadeOut(1,function(){
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(320).html(arr_val()).fadeOut(1,function(){
$('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(40).html(narr_val()).fadeOut(1,function(){
```

etc...there is a version with 27 blocks and another one with 40. [Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/hnkhZ/)

```
}); }); }); }); }); }); }); }); }); }); }); }); }); }); }); });
```

My questions: 
1) Any other way of doing this instead of using embedded callback functions? 
2) Any way to write that syntax with a for loop or something that would avoid writing 27 blocks of callback functions?

Comment: Yes, there probably is. Have you looked at the queue system? I don't think you need any of those callbacks.

Comment: Not posting that as an answer since im pretty sure there's a better way, but here that can help you : http://jsfiddle.net/hnkhZ/1/

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to use the built in queuing capability by creating .html call that can be queued (see [jQuery .queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) for more information):

```
function queuedHtml(html) {
    return function () {
        $(this).html(html);
        $(this).dequeue();
    };
}
```

This can be adjusted to use a named queue rather than the default queue.

Once you've done this, you can adjust your code to something like this:

```
$("#foo").bind("click tap", function () {
   var $foo = $("#foo");
   $foo.unbind("click");

   $foo.fadeIn(1).delay(500).queue(queuedHtml('Attention!')).fadeOut(1)
       .fadeIn(1).delay(500).queue(queuedHtml('In 3...')).fadeOut(1)
       .fadeIn(1).delay(500).queue(queuedHtml('2...')).fadeOut(1)
       .fadeIn(1).delay(500).queue(queuedHtml('1...')).fadeOut(1)
       .fadeIn(1).delay(500).queue(queuedHtml('Go!')).fadeOut(1);

   for (var i = 0; i < 27; ++i) {
       $foo.fadeIn(1).delay(175).queue(queuedHtml(narr_val())).fadeOut(1)
           .fadeIn(1).delay(40).queue(queuedHtml(key_val())).fadeOut(1)
           .fadeIn(1).delay(175).queue(queuedHtml(narr_val())).fadeOut(1)
           .fadeIn(1).delay(320).queue(queuedHtml(arr_val())).fadeOut(1)
           .fadeIn(1).delay(40).queue(queuedHtml(narr_val())).fadeOut(1);
   }

   $foo.fadeIn(1).queue(queuedHtml('Terminated'));
});
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnkhZ/2/)

You can reduce the code a bit further by refactoring out some of the repetitive logic - for example:

```
function addToQueue($el, html, delay) {
    $el.fadeIn(1).delay(delay).queue(queuedHtml(html)).fadeOut(1);
}

$("#foo").bind("click tap", function () {
   var $foo = $("#foo");
   $foo.unbind("click");

   addToQueue($foo, 'Attention!', 500);
   addToQueue($foo, 'In 3...', 500);
   addToQueue($foo, '2...', 500);
   addToQueue($foo, '1...', 500);
   addToQueue($foo, 'Go!', 500);

   for (var i = 0; i < 27; ++i) {
       addToQueue($foo, narr_val(), 175);
       addToQueue($foo, key_val(), 40);
       addToQueue($foo, narr_val(), 175);
       addToQueue($foo, arr_val(), 320);
       addToQueue($foo, narr_val(), 40);
   }

   $foo.fadeIn(1).queue(queuedHtml('Terminated'));
});
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnkhZ/3/)

or reduce it even further by a bit more refactoring:

```
$("#foo").bind("click tap", function () {
   var $foo = $("#foo");
   $foo.unbind("click");

   $.each(['Attention', 'In 3...', '2...', '1...', 'Go!'], function(idx, val) {
       addToQueue($foo, val, 500);
   });

   var delays = [175, 40, 175, 320, 40];
   for (var i = 0; i < 27; ++i) {
       $.each([narr_val(), key_val(), narr_val(), arr_val(), narr_val()], function(idx, val) {
           addToQueue($foo, val, delays[idx]);
       });
   }

   $foo.fadeIn(1).queue(queuedHtml('Terminated'));
});
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnkhZ/4/)

Comment: @dc5: That's an amazing reduction in the length of code! Thanks also for the step by step demonstration. However, one issue that remains, and I don't understand why, is that the timing does not seem to be respected. The longest delay, 320ms, occurs on an animal word. This means that this word should be perceived on the screen. Rather, the longer delay occurs on a non-word. So it seems like the delay is not applied on the right array value.

Comment: The logic is currently adding the delay before setting the html, so the delay of 320 is occurring just before setting the animal word.  The animal word is showing up for 40ms (the last delay value).  If that isn't what you want, you can switch the call to queue the html with the delay: `$el.fadeIn(1).queue(queuedHtml(html)).delay(delay).fadeOut(1);`

Comment: ok, got it, thanks! Just changing the delays variable to:                   var delays = [40, 175, 40, 175, 320]; makes it mimic exactly what I had.

Comment: Thinking about it more, you might get a better affect with this chain: fadeOut -> update html -> fadeIn -> delay with longer fadeIn/Out values like this: `$el.fadeOut(100).queue(queuedHtml(html)).fadeIn(100).delay(delay);`  As it stands now, the 1ms fadeIn/Out values probably aren't necessary - you may as well remove them if you want an abrupt transition.

Comment: @Fred - I see where I went wrong - in your callback version, the `.html` call occurred immediately after the call to `.delay` as that version isn't queued.  I hadn't accounted for that in making the queued version.

Comment: @dc5 - you're also right on the unnecessary use of fadeIn and fadeOut. I think it remains there from my initial tryouts. Sorry, I just learned jQuery last week. More use to Perl and ActionScript, but needed this to run on an Ipad.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with async stuff you need to use recursive functions instead of for loops to do your iteration. Without using any libraries, one possible approach would be something along the lines of

```
var aims = [
    {delay:500, html:'Attention!'},
    {delay:500, html:'In 3...'},
    ...
];

function loop(i){
    if(i >= anims.length){
        //ANIMATION DONE
    }else{
        var a = anims[i];
        $('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(a.delay).html(a.html).fadeOut(1,function(){
            loop(i+1);
        });
    }
}

loop(0);
```

---

The most direct way to avoid callback nesting in Javascript is to use named callbacks instead of anonymous ones. For example:

```
function f1(){ $('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(500).html('Attention!').fadeOut(1, f2); }
function f2(){ $('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(500).html('In 3...').fadeOut(1,f2); }
function f3(){ ... }
```

Of course, having a bunch of hardcoded f1, f2, f3, fn... names is error prone and not maintainable at all. What you can do is give each step function its continuation as a parameter

```
var steps = [
    function (next){ $('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(500).html('Attention!').fadeOut(1, next); },
    function (next){ $('#foo').fadeIn(1).delay(500).html('In 3...').fadeOut(1, next); },
    ...
];
```

And then use a chaining function to call each step in sequence, passing the next step as a parameter:

```
function chain(steps, onDone){
    function loop(i){
        if(i >= steps.length){
            onDone();
        )else{
            steps[i](function(){
                loop(i+1);
            });
        }
     }
     loop(0);
 }

 chain(steps, function(){ console.log("all done") });
```

There are many libraries out there (either callback or promise based)  that offer these chaining functions if you dont want to implement them yourself.